# Speeding up Redshift COPY loading

Tags: performance, optimization, amazon-redshift

I am loading files into Redshift with the COPY command using a manifest. The files are in S3. Unfortunately, there's about 2,000 files per table, so it's like

users1.csv.gz, users2.csv.gz, users3.csv.gz, users4.csv.gz, etc

I don't know if that matters or not, because the files are loaded with a manifest, and the manifest is supposed to parallelize this. That being said, it is really slow to load a table, and I need to speed it up.

What are some things I could do to speed this up?

Comment: I wonder if the manifest is slowing things down? You can use the COPY command without a manifest if all files are in a particular path, eg `COPY table1 FROM 's3://bucketname/path/users'`. This will load all files in that path that have filenames starting with `users`. See if that speeds things up. Aside from that, having more nodes will speed the load process since it is parallelized. You can always scale-down later.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was importing lots of small tables (~100 tables of less than 1k rows each). In this case, adding the following options did help:

```
COMPUPDATE OFF
```

and

```
STATUPDATE OFF
```

- [documentation for COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)
- [documentation for COMPUPDATE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Loading_tables_auto_compress.html).
- [documentation for STATUPDATE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-statupdate)

Keep in mind that this does skip automatic compression and stats update. Refer to the documentation for the exact consequences of this.

Comment: if you copy to a brandnew table then the COMPUPDATE OFF and STATUPDATE OFF will be ignored by Redshift. Redshift will run COMPUPDATE and STATUPDATE anyway when it realise the table has no data.

Comment: @HarryDuong, could you point where this information is in the documentation, please? I could not find it.

Comment: @gabra:  you can find it here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Analyzing_tables.html

"In addition, the COPY command performs an analysis automatically when it loads data into an empty table."

The Analyse operation the trigger STATUPDATE. (I may be wrong about COMPUPDATE)

Answer (score 2):

1. If the size of the each user*.csv.gz file is very small, then Redshift  might be spending some compute effort in uncompressing. If it is small, you may consider, uploading the csv files directly without compressing.
2. If you may want only specific columns from the CSV, you may use the column list to ignore a few columns. The below link describes column lists.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html#copy-column-list
3. You may disable the COMPUPDATE option during load if it is unnecessary.
4. Is it an empty table or does the table possess any data. If so, please execute VACUUM and ANALYSE commands before/after the load. VACUUM & ANALYSE are time consuming activities as well, if thr is any sort key and the data in your csv is also in the same sorted order, the above operation should be faster.
5. Define relevant sort keys which will have an impact on disk I/O and columnar compression & Load data in the sort key order. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key-order.html
6. Define relevant distribution styles, which will distribute data across multiple slices and will impact disk I/O across the cluster.
7. Specify compression types for columns which reduces disk size and disk I/O subsequenty.

May I know the numbers, how many records in total and how long does it take to load?

Hope the above points help